# Display bookmark link on detail page to inline VF page

Tags: visualforce, page-layout, standardsetcontroller, inline-visualforce

How can I display an inline visualforce page on a page layout and have Salesforce generate the bookmark link at the top of the detail page, like it does for related lists?

Currently, I can do this with jquery and modifying the DOM, but was wondering if there is a standard or more supported way of providing the bookmark link, perhaps using the standardsetcontroller?

Comment: There's an idea for [Visualforce Related List Hover Link Support](http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ZQo4AAG)

Comment: Peter, thanks for the link, but that's a slightly different scenario.  I'm not using the apex:relatedList element, but rather a custom vf page w/ a pageblock element to mimic the related list functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asfaik, there's no way of generating the hover links at the top in a vf page other than handcrafting it, like you've described.

I've had the same problem where we did a custom vf section to display a customised related list on a standard page, an had to live with no out of the box related list hover links. Much needed!

Comment: Yeah, that's the same use case I have (and have had before).  A custom related list.  Bummer, would be great to have.  Thanks for the feedback.