# Bookmark and hover functionality like Standard Related List for inline VF page

Tags: visualforce, page-layout, related-list, inline-visualforce

I have a inLine VF page on my Standard Account Page which shows the list of related custom objects.I have a requirement where in I would like like to have a bookmark on top of the page so that when user clicks on it, it will take the user directly to that inLine VF Page.I know we can achieve this with replacing the Standard page with Custom  Page.

I came to know that there is an idea [Visualforce Related List Hover Link Support](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ZQo4AAG)  for something like this as well

As per the post [Display bookmark link on detail page to inline VF page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3582/display-bookmark-link-on-detail-page-to-inline-vf-page),we can not achieve this .As a workaround, we would need to play a trick with jquery.But that was 4 years ago.

As salesforce comes up with amazing new features with new releases pretty fast, I would like to know if something has changed in the past 4 years in context to this functionality.Has some been able to find some different workaround for something like this

Comment: Do you just mean sending the user to a page anchor?

Comment: Yes @AdrianLarson , Something like that